# How were the gamers transported to the hospitals in Sword Art Online?

Tags: sword-art-online

Did the light novels (or manga) ever explain how the medical personnel were able to get the trapped gamers from their homes to the hospital without the NerveGear frying the gamers? From the anime's description, it should have been impossible, since the NerveGear would've killed anyone was physically disconnected from the game.

Comment: Just for the info, *Sword Art Online* originated from the light novel, not from the manga, unless you're really asking about the manga adaptation.

Comment: @AkiTanaka, thanks for clarifying - I don't mind an answer from either the light novels or the manga. Thought it might be a plot hole, but hoping to find an answer either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the NerveGear has a Battery

> It also has a battery and internal memory to store data from the games. 30% of the NerveGear's weight is from its internal battery.

Source: [NerveGear > Appearance](https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/NerveGear#Appearance)

according to the citation this was revealed in Volume 1 Chapter 3 of the Light Novel

Kirito also points this out in the first episode when Kayaba is addressing the players in the Town of Beginnings about the start of the Death Game

> When Klein voiced his doubts on the situation, Kirito confirmed that the NerveGear's signals essentially functioned like microwaves, thus it was indeed plausible for them to cause lethal brain damage if the safeties were disabled. Kirito also explained the helmet had an internal battery, which rendered Klein's proposal to disconnect it from its power source meaningless.

Source: [Sword Art Online Episode 01 > Plot (7th Paragraph)](https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_Episode_01#Plot)

> **Klein**:  What's that guy talking about he's gotta be nuts. Right Kirito?
> **Kirito**: He's right that the transmitter's signals work just like microwaves.  If the safety were disabled it could fry a brain.
> **Klein**:  Then, if we cut the power…
> **Kirito**:  No, the NerveGear has an internal battery.

Source: [Sword Art Online Episode 1 Animebreakdown.com](https://animebreakdown4u.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/sword-art-online-episode-1-animebreakdown-com/)

and as Kayaba mentions there had already been deaths due to people trying to remove the NerveGear despite his warnings. so either medical professional found out about the battery  or Kayaba had told them for the sake of making sure the players didn't just start dying off

Comment: Was the network connection maintained somehow during transport to the hospital?

Comment: @JW8 No, later in the first volume it's explained how in the first weeks of the game, players would experience a kind of disconnection visual for a couple hours, in the timeframe that it took their bodies to be moved to the hospital. This was possible, because Kayaba allowed players to be disconnected from the network for no longer than two hours (as explained in the same Light Novel chapter above).

Comment: @TUSF, thanks! That clarifies that point - the anime didn't explicitly make it clear that Kayaba allowed users to be temporarily disconnected from the network.